# how to limit string partten is typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have some type like this

```
type ActionType = 'TypeA' | 'TypeB' | 'TypeC' | 'TypeD';
```

I want myActionType is a string, and satisfy it is one of the ActionType or a series of ActionType join with ','

```
const myActionType = "TypeA";
// or
const myActionType = "TypeB,TypeC,TypeA";
```

How to write the type to limit it

Comment: Is there a maximum length of the string? If there is no maximum length, then this is not possible without a helper function.

Comment: @caTS: Oh? I believe you but I would have thought there would be an answer like `type ActionTypes = ActionType | (ActionType + ',' + ActionTypes);`

Comment: @JSmart523 See for yourself: https://tsplay.dev/N5zJZm

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define a generic type using conditional and recursive logic.

```
type MyCommaSeparatedType<T,K> = 
    T extends `${infer R1},${infer R2}` ? 
        R1 extends K ? 
        `${R1},${MyCommaSeparatedType<R2,K>}` : never : T extends K ? 
            T : never;
```

Then use this type as type of the argument in a helper function.

```
const MyCommaSeparatedFunction = <T,K extends ActionType = ActionType>(value: MyCommaSeparatedType<T,K>) => value
```

Now you can use this function to achieve what you intended.

*Examples:*

```
const value1 = MyCommaSeparatedFunction("TypeA")   
//value1 type is  "TypeA"

const value2 = MyCommaSeparatedFunction("TypeB,TypeA,TypeC")   
//value2  type is "TypeB,TypeA,TypeC"

const value3 = MyCommaSeparatedFunction("TypeC$TypeA")    
// value3 type is never
```

Comment: perhaps，you have misunderstood the question.
I want compose `ActionType` as a new Type to limit a string.
the string is satisfied  one of the ActionType or a series of ActionType join with ','

```ts
type NewActionType = SomeWayToCompose<ActionType>;
```